# Increasing Connection Limit of StrongSwan VPN (L2TP/IPSec)

Tags: vpn, ipsec, strongswan

I have VPN server and I have approximately 500 customers and all of them using same username/password credential to connect my VPN server but connection issues starting after connecting 250 users to VPN server.

How can I increase the limit of concurrent connections? (There is no load on the server)

Comment: Use a larger ip address range.

Answer (score 0):

Configure the server with more available IP addresses with for example

```
rightsourceip=10.30.20.0/22
```

for 1024 addresses.

Comment: I am using this: rightsourceip=192.168.1.0/24 and I will try 192.168.1.0/22

Comment: a /24 is 256 addresses which is close to the point you report having an issue.